# How do I test a next js api route which uses next-connect?

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, next.js, next-connect

I followed this article [here](https://seanconnolly.dev/unit-testing-nextjs-api-routes), to try testing a simple api route in Next.js.

This article uses [node-mocks-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http) to mock req and res objects.

It works with normal next api (which doesn't use next-connect, eg. described in the article above), but when I try to use it with an api which uses next-connect, jest throws a timeout error.

```
Error: Exceeded timeout of 5000ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase
```

Looks like the api doesn't respond, but it works when I try it normally through the browser.

Comment: Have you tried extending the `timeout` value using `jest.setTimeout(value)` inside your test file ?

Comment: If that doesn't work can check this a possible workaround https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10094#issuecomment-761803348

Comment: @Lokenath Karmakar Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: having the same issue here. works really fine without `next-connect`. I am also using `node-mocks-http`